# Can't get Content on ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

There's probably something silly happening here but I can't do something very basic. I have an `ArrayController` that who's `content` property has four array items within it. Here's the screenshot from the Ember Inspector:

[image: inspector]

If I type `$E.get('content')` where $E is pointing to the ArrayController object, I'd expect to get back a reference to this array. Instead I get "undefined". If I instead click on the Inspector's UI to assign $E to the content property off of the ArrayController this works fine.

Very odd and it's causing me problems outside the Inspector as well so any help people could offer would be greatly appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

Some additional context ...

The ArrayController I'm referring to is one that get's instantiated in a somewhat different way than normal. This variation is possibly part of the problem so here's the details:

My model definition looks like this:

```
App.Enum = DS.Model.extend(App.CouchDocPropsMixin,{
  data: DS.attr("EnumData"
      defaultValue: function() {
           var object = App.EnumData.create();
           var initialProp = Ember.Object.create({id:"value",name:"name"});
           object.pushObject(initialProp);
           return object;
      }
  }),
  desc: DS.attr("prose"),
  type: DS.attr("string")
});
```

For both `prose` and `EnumData` there is a need to build a serializer/deserializer. Prose can be ignored because it's nothing more than a long string which I wanted the type system to see slightly differently. The possible conflict is with EnumData and how it's used. What the deserializer is doing is taking a dictionary data structure (ala, what a PHP associative array serializes to) and converting it to a more Ember-like flat object:

`{foo: {bar:baz}}` becomes `{id:foo, bar:baz})`

```
App.EnumDataTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
        var enumData = App.EnumData.create();
        for (var property in serialized) {
            serialized[property].id = property;
            enumData.pushObject(serialized[property]);
        }
        return enumData;
    },  
    serialize: function(deserialized) {
        var response = {};
        if(deserialized.length) {
            deserialized.forEach(function(item) {
                var id = item.id;
                delete item.id;
                response[id] = item;
            });
        }
        return response;
    }
});
```

The last part of this context is the EnumData object definition which is a generic ArrayController for now. I intend at some point to add some computed properties to it but that's once I get the basics working:

```
App.EnumData = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
     // generic for now
});
```

Anyway, that is the rather long-winded story of how the ArrayController in the example came to be.

Comment: This view is a little weird to me, it doesn't look like you're looking at an array controller, despite it saying it's a controller.  Which then makes me wonder what type `Enum` and `EnumData` are, and how you're getting a reference to the ArrayController from this view (I could just not recognize this).  Additionally have you checked to see if it's the same instance of the array controller?  Also generally `content` isn't a computed property on an array controller, it's usually just a property, and `model` is aliased to it, Will you show the ArrayController's definition?

Comment: Good suggestion @kingpin2k, i have added the additional context now.